# ¿Cómo seleccionar un elemento de una columna que esta en formato lista?

Tags: r, rstudio, filtro, r-dplyr

Estoy aprendiendo la librería dplyr de R y estoy practicando con el dataset **starwars**

Necesito seleccionar una película en concreto a partir de unos filtros previos que vengo realizando, pero como la columna "films" esta en formato lista no se como hacerlo.

`$ films     :List of 87 ..$ : chr [1:5] "The Empire Strikes Back" "Revenge of the Sith" "Return of the Jedi" "A New Hope"`

Si coloco :
`test=starwars %>% filter(species =="Human", height >=170) %>% filter(films == "Attack of the Clones")`

Solo me toma las filas con esa única película, pero no las otras filas que tambien la contienen `(c("The Empire Strikes Back", "Attack of the Clones"` como por ejemplo esa.

Necesitaría una ayuda para saber como acceder a que me filtre tambien en ese caso, o si tengo que realizar algún otro paso previo para resolverlo.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para esto puede ser muy útil usar [`tidyr::unnest()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html), que "expande" una columna tipo lista en filas.

```
starwars %>% 
  unnest(films) %>% 
  filter(species =="Human", 
         height >=170,
         films %in% c("The Empire Strikes Back", "Attack of the Clones")) %>%
  select(name, films)

# A tibble: 20 x 2
   name                films                  
   <chr>               <chr>                  
 1 Luke Skywalker      The Empire Strikes Back
 2 Darth Vader         The Empire Strikes Back
 3 Owen Lars           Attack of the Clones   
 4 Obi-Wan Kenobi      The Empire Strikes Back
 5 Obi-Wan Kenobi      Attack of the Clones   
 6 Anakin Skywalker    Attack of the Clones   
 7 Han Solo            The Empire Strikes Back
 8 Wedge Antilles      The Empire Strikes Back
 9 Palpatine           The Empire Strikes Back
10 Palpatine           Attack of the Clones   
11 Boba Fett           The Empire Strikes Back
12 Boba Fett           Attack of the Clones   
13 Lando Calrissian    The Empire Strikes Back
14 Lobot               The Empire Strikes Back
15 Mace Windu          Attack of the Clones   
16 Gregar Typho        Attack of the Clones   
17 Cliegg Lars         Attack of the Clones   
18 Dooku               Attack of the Clones   
19 Bail Prestor Organa Attack of the Clones   
20 Jango Fett          Attack of the Clones
```

---

Claro que finalmente terminarás con un `tibble` con más filas de las originales, si no es lo que quieres, puedes volver a "comprimir" los `films` mediante `nest()`:

```
starwars %>% 
  unnest(films) %>% 
  filter(species =="Human", 
         height >=170,
         films %in% c("The Empire Strikes Back", "Attack of the Clones")) %>%
  nest(films = films
)

# A tibble: 17 x 14
   name      height  mass hair_color  skin_color eye_color birth_year sex   gender homeworld species
   <chr>      <int> <dbl> <chr>       <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>  
 1 Luke Sky…    172  77   blond       fair       blue            19   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human  
 2 Darth Va…    202 136   none        white      yellow          41.9 male  mascu… Tatooine  Human  
 3 Owen Lars    178 120   brown, grey light      blue            52   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human  
 4 Obi-Wan …    182  77   auburn, wh… fair       blue-gray       57   male  mascu… Stewjon   Human  
 5 Anakin S…    188  84   blond       fair       blue            41.9 male  mascu… Tatooine  Human  
 6 Han Solo     180  80   brown       fair       brown           29   male  mascu… Corellia  Human  
 7 Wedge An…    170  77   brown       fair       hazel           21   male  mascu… Corellia  Human  
 8 Palpatine    170  75   grey        pale       yellow          82   male  mascu… Naboo     Human  
 9 Boba Fett    183  78.2 black       fair       brown           31.5 male  mascu… Kamino    Human  
10 Lando Ca…    177  79   black       dark       brown           31   male  mascu… Socorro   Human  
11 Lobot        175  79   none        light      blue            37   male  mascu… Bespin    Human  
12 Mace Win…    188  84   none        dark       brown           72   male  mascu… Haruun K… Human  
13 Gregar T…    185  85   black       dark       brown           NA   male  mascu… Naboo     Human  
14 Cliegg L…    183  NA   brown       fair       blue            82   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human  
15 Dooku        193  80   white       fair       brown          102   male  mascu… Serenno   Human  
16 Bail Pre…    191  NA   black       tan        brown           67   male  mascu… Alderaan  Human  
17 Jango Fe…    183  79   black       tan        brown           66   male  mascu… Concord … Human  
# … with 3 more variables: vehicles <list>, starships <list>, films <list>
```

---

Otra forma, es usar [`purrr::map_lgl()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html) para aplicar una función sobre cada lista de la columna `films`:

```
starwars %>%
  filter(species =="Human", 
         height >=170,
         map_lgl(films, 
                 ~ any(. %in% c("The Empire Strikes Back","Attack of the Clones")))
  )
```

Comment: Patricio, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, al final termine usando `purr::map_lgl()` ya que luego quería hallar la media de mis filtros y no quería que se me generaran mas filas de forma innecesaria. Saludos!